# The Lotka-Volterra predator-prey model

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, homework, ecology

I have a *Mathematica* assignment where we need to numerically solve a [Lotka-Volterra predator-prey population equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equations). 
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=ax-bxy,\quad\frac{dy}{dt}=-cx+dxy,$$
where $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}_+$.

So far, I have managed to come up with this for the representation of the equation in *Mathematica*:

```
s = DSolve[{x'[t] == a x[t] - b x[t] y[t], y'[t] == -c y[t] + d x[t] y[t]}, {x[t], y[t]}, t]
```

However, I am having trouble getting the equation to plot. I have been trying to use:

```
Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. s], {t, 0, 20}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

as I have found online, but nothing shows on the plot.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? I am new to *Mathematica*.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Be sure that all your constants have been assigned numerical values before plotting the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I tried setting all my variables, just by saying a=1, b=1, c=1, d=1 (or 1, 2, 3, 4) to no avail.

Comment: It strongly looks as a homework.

Answer (score 18):

**The dimensional phase-space plot**

The analysis of the predator-prey model is incomplete without the [phase-space plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equations). So, here it is,

```
a = 2/3; b = 4/3; c = 1; d = 1;

sol[x0_?NumericQ] := First@NDSolve[{x'[t] == a*x[t] - b*x[t]*y[t], y'[t] == c*x[t]*y[t] -
d*y[t], x[0] == x0, y[0] == x0}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 20}];

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol[#] & /@ Range[0.9, 1.8, 0.1]], {t, 0, 20}, 
PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

**The dimensionless Lotka–Volterra equations**

Following the lecture [notes](https://www.math.ust.hk/~machas/mathematical-biology.pdf) for Mathematical Biology by Jeffrey R. Chasnov ( section 1.4 page no. 11), we can have the dimensionless equations in the following form,

$$\frac{d U}{dt}=r(U-UV),\quad \frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{1}{r}(UV-V),$$

where $r=\sqrt{\alpha/\beta}$, a nondimensional parameter. In the notes, the author has solved the above system using Matlab numerical solver `ode45`. Here, I will reproduce his results using *Mathematica*.

The solution to the above system is found using `ParametricNDSolveValue` for different values of $r$.

```
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{U'[t] == r*(U[t] - U[t]*V[t]), 
   V'[t] == 1/r*(U[t]*V[t] - V[t]), U[0] == 1.1, V[0] == 1}, {U,V}, {t, 0, 20}, {r}];

GraphicsColumn[{Plot[{Evaluate[sol[0.5][[1]]][t], 
    Evaluate[sol[0.5][[2]]][t]}, {t, 0, 19}, AspectRatio -> .4, 
   ImageSize -> 500, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[LineLegend[{Red, Directive[Green, Dashed]}, {"prey", 
       "predator"}], {0.89, 0.89}], PlotRange -> {{0, 19}, {0.8, 1.25}}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Directive[Green, Dashed]}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[.003], 
   FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
   PlotRangePadding -> None, ImagePadding -> {{20, 1}, {20, 30}}, 
   Epilog -> {Text[Style["r=0.5", 20], Scaled[{0.6, 0.9}]]}], 
  Plot[{Evaluate[sol[1][[1]]][t], Evaluate[sol[1][[2]]][t]}, {t, 0, 
    19}, AspectRatio -> .4, PlotRange -> {{0, 19}, {0.8, 1.25}}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Directive[Green, Dashed]}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[.003], 
   FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
   PlotRangePadding -> None, ImagePadding -> {{20, 1}, {20, 30}}, 
   Epilog -> {Text[Style["r=1", 20], Scaled[{0.6, 0.9}]]}], 
  Plot[{Evaluate[sol[2][[1]]][t], Evaluate[sol[2][[2]]][t]}, {t, 0, 
    19}, AspectRatio -> .4, PlotRange -> {{0, 19}, {0.8, 1.25}}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Directive[Green, Dashed]}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[.003], 
   FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
   PlotRangePadding -> None, ImagePadding -> {{20, 1}, {20, 30}}, 
   Epilog -> {Text[Style["r=2", 20], Scaled[{0.6, 0.9}]]}]}, 
 ImageSize -> 500, Spacings -> -50]
```

[image]

Finally, plotting the phase-space plot for different values of $r$. For this I have utilized once again `?NumericQ`.

```
sol[r_?NumericQ, U0_?NumericQ] :=First@NDSolve[{U'[t] == r*(U[t] - U[t]*V[t]),
V'[t] == 1/r*(U[t]*V[t] - V[t]), U[0] == U0, V[0] == U0}, {U,V}, {t, 0, 20}];

Grid[{{ParametricPlot[
    Evaluate[{U[t], V[t]} /. sol[0.5, #] & /@ 
      Range[0.9, 1.8, 0.1]], {t, 0, 20}, Frame -> True, 
    Epilog -> {Text[Style["r=0.5", 20], Scaled[{0.8, 0.8}]]}, 
    ImageSize -> 200, PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 4}}], 
   ParametricPlot[
    Evaluate[{U[t], V[t]} /. sol[1, #] & /@ Range[0.9, 1.8, 0.1]], {t,
      0, 20}, Frame -> True, 
    Epilog -> {Text[Style["r=1", 20], Scaled[{0.8, 0.8}]]}, 
    ImageSize -> 200, PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 4}}], 
   ParametricPlot[
    Evaluate[{U[t], V[t]} /. sol[2, #] & /@ Range[0.9, 1.8, 0.1]], {t,
      0, 20}, Frame -> True, 
    Epilog -> {Text[Style["r=2", 20], Scaled[{0.8, 0.8}]]}, 
    ImageSize -> 200, PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 4}}]}}]
```

[image]

The simply way to plot the phase planes of system is to use `StreamPlot`

```
Grid[{{With[{r = 0.5}, 
    StreamPlot[{r*(U - U*V), 1/r*(U*V - V)}, {U, 0, 5}, {V, 0, 5}, 
     Epilog -> {Text[Style["r=0.5", 20], Scaled[{0.8, 0.8}]]}]], 
   With[{r = 1}, 
    StreamPlot[{r*(U - U*V), 1/r*(U*V - V)}, {U, 0, 5}, {V, 0, 5}, 
     Epilog -> {Text[Style["r=1", 20], Scaled[{0.8, 0.8}]]}]], 
   With[{r = 2}, 
    StreamPlot[{r*(U - U*V), 1/r*(U*V - V)}, {U, 0, 5}, {V, 0, 5}, 
     Epilog -> {Text[Style["r=2", 20], Scaled[{0.8, 0.8}]]}]]}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

This code presented in this answer is essentially the same as the code given by DumpsterDoofus. I just want to point out the importance of having meaningful values for the parameters and initial conditions. I also want to show one might explore the parameter space with a `Manipulate` expression.

One of the phenomena demonstrated by the Lotka-Volterra model is that, under certain conditions, the predator and prey populations are cyclic with a phase shift between them. Here is a demonstration of this effect.

```
lv = 
  With[{a = 1.5, b = 1., c = 3., d = 1.},
    With[{x0 = 10., y0 = 6.}, 
      NDSolve[
        {x'[t] == a x[t] - b x[t] y[t], y'[t] == -c y[t] + d x[t] y[t], 
         x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0}, 
        {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 20}]]]

Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. lv], {t, 0, 20}]
```

[image: plot]

The static formulation is easily transformed into a dynamic one.

```
Manipulate[
  lv = NDSolve[
    {x'[t] == a x[t] - b x[t] y[t], y'[t] == -c y[t] + d x[t] y[t], 
    x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 20}]; 
  Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. lv], {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0,0}],
  {{lv, {}}, None},
  {{x0, 10}, 5, 30, 1},
  {{y0, 6}, 2, 20, 1},
  {{a, 1.5}, 1., 4.},
  {{b, 1.}, 1., 4.},
  {{c, 3.}, 1., 4.},
  {{d, 1.}, .1, 2.}]
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 10):

You forgot to specify initial conditions on $x$ and $y$, which makes plotting impossible. However, even when initial conditions are specified, `DSolve` seems to choke on some sort of inverse-function garbage, so I'll sidestep it by using `NDSolve` instead (I'll let others determine why the analytic solution doesn't work):

```
{a, b, c, d} = {1, 2, 3, 4};
{X, Y} = NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == a x[t] - b x[t] y[t], 
    y'[t] == -c y[t] + d x[t] y[t], x[0] == 1, y[0] == 1}, {x, y}, {t,
     0, 1}];
Plot[{X[t], Y[t]}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for this reply! I had tried setting initial conditions on x and y before, but I didn't seem to help so I had been adding and removing them in and out.

This looks like exactly what I need! However, I tried to type it up myself, and am getting an error "There are fewer dependent variables, {y[t]}, than equations, so the
system is overdetermined."

Comment: @elykl33t: You can just copy and paste the code in my answer and execute it (no need to manually type it). Restart the kernel to make sure you don't have any stray definitions floating around, as that's a very common mistake.

Comment: that was it! I initially did copy paste, and only tried the typing when it didn't work. I forget about the kernel restart! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no close-form answer because the solution is implicit. An equation of the phase plot can be obtained, however:

$$\frac{dy} { dx} =\frac{ (- c y + d x y) }{ (a x - b x y)} $$

which can rewritten as

$$\left(\frac{a}{y} - b\right) dy = \left(d -\frac{ c}{x}\right) dx$$

Hence the implicit equation of the phase plot that you can draw with, say,

**ContourPlot**:

```
a Log[y] - b y - d x + c Log[x] = Cte.
```

`NDSolve` must be used instead of `DSolve` which cannot invert this equation, wherein time information is absent.

I recommend you study it by hand, beginning with the variations of a `y -> Log[y] - b y`  and `x -> - d x + c Log[x]`, showing that a value is usually reached twice (this explains why the curve is a closed one, a.k.a. 'potato' :) ).