# How to generate a phase plane plot from data points?

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

I have a list of points

```
Rabbits={{0,20},{0.01,20.0024},{0.02,20.0071}...}

Foxes={{0,40},{0.01,39.76},{0.02,39.5214}...}
```

I want to create a phase plane with these points. I've tried using `ParametricPlot`,

```
ParametricPlot[{Rabbits, Foxes}, {t, 0, 100}]
```

But `Mathematica` keep running. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should share your complete data.

Answer (score 1):

**`ListStreamPlot`**

Are you looking for something like this?

```
data = Table[{{x, y}, {y, x - x^2}}, {x, -1.5, 1.5, 0.2}, {y, -2, 2, 0.2}];
ListStreamPlot[data]
```

**Edit**

**`ParametricPlot`**

Since you haven't provided a complete data. So, I will generate my own while taking data from a [predator-prey model](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/74214/the-lotka-volterra-predator-prey-model/137826#137826), to make my response more relevant to the question.

```
sol = With[{r = 0.5}, NDSolve[{U'[t] == r*(U[t] - U[t]*V[t]), 
     V'[t] == 1/r*(U[t]*V[t] - V[t]), U[0] == 1.1, V[0] == 1}, {U, 
     V}, {t, 0, 20}]];
```

You can think of `U` to be rabbits density and `V` foxes density.

```
rabbitsdata = Table[Flatten@Evaluate[{t, U[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 20, 0.1}];
foxesdata = Table[Flatten@Evaluate[{t, V[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 20, 0.1}];
```

The structure of the above data is like the one you provided, i.e, `{{time, Rabbitdensity},....}`.

Now, I will interpolate the above data to generate two interpolating functions,

```
{U, V} = ListInterpolation[#, {{0, 20}}] & /@ {rabbitsdata[[All, 2]], foxesdata[[All, 2]]};
```

Finally, plotting the phase-portrait using `ParametricPlot`,

```
ParametricPlot[{U[t], V[t]}, {t, 0, 20}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is perfect!!

Comment: @Deborah_Watson For more details about this, you should search `ListStreamPlot`.

Answer (score 0):

Parametric plot is used to plot parametric functions. In your case you should use `ListPlot` instead.

For this first you need list of two tuples like `{{20,40},{20.0024,39.76}....}`. 
This can be achieved as follows:

```
Transpose[{Transpose[Rabbits[[2, All]]], Transpose[Foxes[[2, All]]]}]
```

Once you are done, you can use `ListPlot` to get desired output:

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{Transpose[Rabbits[[2, All]]], Transpose[Foxes[[2, All]]]}], PlotRange->All]
```

Comment: This is just the thing I wanted, thank you soo much. I can't believe how simple that was!!!