# Solving a system of fractional differential equations

Tags: differential-equations

I have adopted the method in the [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/239669/could-anyone-please-suggest-me-mathematica-code-to-solve-fractional-order-time-d) to solve a much simpler [system](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/74214/the-lotka-volterra-predator-prey-model/137826#137826) but it takes ages to execute.

```
a1 = 2/3; b1 = 4/3; c1 = 1; d1 = 1; x0 = 0.9; y0 = 1.8;
\[Alpha] = 1; h = .0025;

tau = 0.15; nn = Round[tau/h]; smax = Round[15/tau]; n = nn*smax;

f[t_, x_, y_] := a1*x - b1*x*y;
g[t_, x_, y_] := c1*x*y - d1*y;

Do[x[i] = x0; y[i] = y0, {i, -nn, 0}];

For[k = 1, k <= n, k++, b[k] = k^\[Alpha] - (k - 1)^\[Alpha] ;
a[k] = -(2*k^(\[Alpha] + 1)) + (k - 1)^(\[Alpha] + 1) + (k +
1)^(\[Alpha] + 1);];

Do[Do[x1[i] = x[i - nn]; y1[i] = y[i - nn];, {i, 0, s*nn}];
For[j = 1, j <= s*nn, j++,
p[j] = (h^\[Alpha]*Sum[b[j - A]*f[A*h, x[A], y[A]], {A, 0, j - 1}])/
Gamma[\[Alpha] + 1] + x[0];
l[j] = (h^\[Alpha]*
Sum[b[j - B]*g[B*h, x1[B], y[B]], {B, 0, j - 1}])/
Gamma[\[Alpha] + 1] + y[0];
x[j] = (h^\[Alpha]*(Sum[
a[j - K]*f[h*K, x[K], y1[K]], {K, 1, j - 1}] +
f[h*j, p[j],
l[j]] + ((j - 1)^(\[Alpha] + 1) - (-\[Alpha] + j - 1)*
j^\[Alpha])*f[0, x[0], y[0]]))/Gamma[\[Alpha] + 2] + x[0];
y[j] = (h^\[Alpha]*(Sum[
a[j - F]*g[F*h, x1[F], y[F]], {F, 1, j - 1}] +
g[h*j, p[j],
l[j]] + ((j - 1)^(\[Alpha] + 1) - (-\[Alpha] + j - 1)*
j^\[Alpha])*g[0, x[0], y[0]]))/Gamma[\[Alpha] + 2] +
y[0];];, {s, 1, smax}]

lst1 = Table[{x[j], y[j]}, {j, n}];
lst = Table[{x[j], y[j]}, {j, 10, n, 10}];

Clear[x, y];
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == f[t, x[t], y[t - tau]],
y'[t] == g[t, x[t - tau], y[t]], x[t /; t <= 0] == 0.9,
y[t /; t <= 0] == 1.8}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 40}];

{Show[ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol[[1]], {t, .0, 20},
PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {x, y}],
ListPlot[lst1, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True]]}
```

Moreover for smaller steps and for alpha other than 1, the solution doesnt make anysense.

Comment: Could you add more written explanation of your problem?  And what does "FDEs" stand for - fractional differential equations, functional differential equations, fuzzy differential equations, or something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a typo in the code. We should use `y1[A]` in `p[j]` definition. Also for $\alpha<1$ we should take very small step `h`, since predictor-corrector algorithm depends on $h^{\alpha}$. For example, if for $\alpha =1$ solution converges at $h=0.01$, then for $\alpha =1/2$ solution converges at $h=10^{-4}$. To test code we put $h=1/100, \alpha =1, 4/5$. As benchmark solution we use `NDSolve` at $\alpha=1$, so we have

```
Clear[x, y];
a1 = 2/3; b1 = 4/3; c1 = 1; d1 = 1; x0 = 0.9; y0 = 1.8;
\[Alpha] = 1; h = .01; par1 = h^\[Alpha]/Gamma[\[Alpha] + 1]; par2 = 
 h^\[Alpha]/Gamma[\[Alpha] + 2];

tau = 0.15; nn = Round[tau/h]; n = 40 nn;

f[t_, x_, y_] := a1*x - b1*x*y;
g[t_, x_, y_] := c1*x*y - d1*y;

Do[x[i] = x0; y[i] = y0, {i, -nn, 0}];

For[k = 1, k <= n, k++, b[k] = k^\[Alpha] - (k - 1)^\[Alpha];
  a[k] = -(2*k^(\[Alpha] + 1)) + (k - 1)^(\[Alpha] + 1) + (k + 
       1)^(\[Alpha] + 1);];

Do[Do[x1[i] = x[i - nn]; y1[i] = y[i - nn];, {i, 0, s*nn}];
  For[j = 1, j <= s*nn, j++, 
   p[j] = (par1 Sum[b[j - A]*f[A*h, x[A], y1[A]], {A, 0, j - 1}]) + 
     x[0];
   l[j] = (par1 Sum[b[j - B]*g[B*h, x1[B], y[B]], {B, 0, j - 1}]) + 
     y[0];
   x[j] = (par2 (Sum[a[j - K]*f[h*K, x[K], y1[K]], {K, 1, j - 1}] + 
         f[h*j, p[j], 
          l[j]] + ((j - 1)^(\[Alpha] + 1) - (-\[Alpha] + j - 1)*
             j^\[Alpha])*f[0, x[0], y[0]])) + x[0];
   y[j] = (par2 (Sum[a[j - F]*g[F*h, x1[F], y[F]], {F, 1, j - 1}] + 
         g[h*j, p[j], 
          l[j]] + ((j - 1)^(\[Alpha] + 1) - (-\[Alpha] + j - 1)*
             j^\[Alpha])*g[0, x[0], y[0]])) + y[0];];, {s, 1, 
   40}] // AbsoluteTiming


lst1 = Table[{x[j], y[j]}, {j, n}];

Clear[x, y];

\[Alpha] = 4/5; h = .01; par1 = h^\[Alpha]/Gamma[\[Alpha] + 1]; par2 =
  h^\[Alpha]/Gamma[\[Alpha] + 2];

tau = 0.15; nn = Round[tau/h]; n = 40 nn;

f[t_, x_, y_] := a1*x - b1*x*y;
g[t_, x_, y_] := c1*x*y - d1*y;

Do[x[i] = x0; y[i] = y0, {i, -nn, 0}];

For[k = 1, k <= n, k++, b[k] = k^\[Alpha] - (k - 1)^\[Alpha];
  a[k] = -(2*k^(\[Alpha] + 1)) + (k - 1)^(\[Alpha] + 1) + (k + 
       1)^(\[Alpha] + 1);];

Do[Do[x1[i] = x[i - nn]; y1[i] = y[i - nn];, {i, 0, s*nn}];
  For[j = 1, j <= s*nn, j++, 
   p[j] = (par1 Sum[b[j - A]*f[A*h, x[A], y1[A]], {A, 0, j - 1}]) + 
     x[0];
   l[j] = (par1 Sum[b[j - B]*g[B*h, x1[B], y[B]], {B, 0, j - 1}]) + 
     y[0];
   x[j] = (par2 (Sum[a[j - K]*f[h*K, x[K], y1[K]], {K, 1, j - 1}] + 
         f[h*j, p[j], 
          l[j]] + ((j - 1)^(\[Alpha] + 1) - (-\[Alpha] + j - 1)*
             j^\[Alpha])*f[0, x[0], y[0]])) + x[0];
   y[j] = (par2 (Sum[a[j - F]*g[F*h, x1[F], y[F]], {F, 1, j - 1}] + 
         g[h*j, p[j], 
          l[j]] + ((j - 1)^(\[Alpha] + 1) - (-\[Alpha] + j - 1)*
             j^\[Alpha])*g[0, x[0], y[0]])) + y[0];];, {s, 1, 
   40}] // AbsoluteTiming
lst2 = Table[{x[j], y[j]}, {j, n}];

Clear[x, y];

a1 = 2/3; b1 = 4/3; c1 = 1; d1 = 1; x0 = 0.9; y0 = 1.8; 
f[t_, x_, y_] := a1*x - b1*x*y;
g[t_, x_, y_] := c1*x*y - d1*y; tau = 0.15;
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == f[t, x[t], y[t - tau]], 
    y'[t] == g[t, x[t - tau], y[t]], x[t /; t <= 0] == 0.9, 
    y[t /; t <= 0] == 1.8}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 40}];


pl1 = ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol[[1]], {t, .0, n h}, 
   PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {x, y}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1/2, PlotStyle -> Green];
```

Visualization

```
Show[pl1, ListLinePlot[lst1, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}], 
 ListLinePlot[lst2, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Dashed}]]
```

[image: Figure 1]

With small modification of the code above we can compute up to `t=15` as follows

```
a1 = 2/3; b1 = 
 4/3; c1 = 1; d1 = 1; x0 = 0.9; y0 = 1.8; \[Alpha] = 1; h = .01; par1 \
= h^\[Alpha]/Gamma[\[Alpha] + 1]; par2 = 
 h^\[Alpha]/Gamma[\[Alpha] + 2];

tau = 0.15; nn = Round[tau/h]; smax = 100; n = smax nn;

f[t_, x_, y_] := a1*x - b1*x*y;
g[t_, x_, y_] := c1*x*y - d1*y;

Do[x[i] = x0; y[i] = y0, {i, -nn, 0}]; f0 = f[0, x[0], y[0]]; g0 = 
 g[0, x[0], y[0]];

For[k = 1, k <= n, k++, b[k] = k^\[Alpha] - (k - 1)^\[Alpha];
  a[k] = -(2*k^(\[Alpha] + 1)) + (k - 1)^(\[Alpha] + 1) + (k + 
       1)^(\[Alpha] + 1); 
  c[k] = ((j - 1)^(\[Alpha] + 1) - (-\[Alpha] + j - 1)*j^\[Alpha])];

Do[Do[x1[i] = x[i - nn]; y1[i] = y[i - nn];, {i, 0, s*nn}];
  For[j = 1, j <= s*nn, j++, bj = Table[b[j - A], {A, 0, j - 1}]; 
   f1j = Table[f[A*h, x[A], y1[A]], {A, 0, j - 1}]; 
   p[j] = par1 bj . f1j + x[0]; 
   g1j = Table[g[B*h, x1[B], y[B]], {B, 0, j - 1}];
   l[j] = par1 bj . g1j + y[0]; aj = Table[a[j - i], {i, 1, j - 1}]; 
   f2j = Table[f[h*Kk, x[Kk], y1[Kk]], {Kk, 1, j - 1}];
   x[j] = par2 (aj . f2j + f[h*j, p[j], l[j]] + c[j] f0) + x[0]; 
   g2j = Table[g[F*h, x1[F], y[F]], {F, 1, j - 1}];
   y[j] = 
    par2 (aj . g2j + g[h*j, p[j], l[j]] + c[j] g0) + y[0];];, {s, 1, 
   smax}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

This part with $\alpha=1$ takes 444s on my laptop.

```
lst1 = Table[{x[j], y[j]}, {j, n}];


Clear[x, y];

a1 = 2/3; b1 = 4/3; c1 = 1; d1 = 1; x0 = 0.9; y0 = 1.8; \[Alpha] = 
 4/5; h = .01; par1 = h^\[Alpha]/Gamma[\[Alpha] + 1]; par2 = 
 h^\[Alpha]/Gamma[\[Alpha] + 2];

tau = 0.15; nn = Round[tau/h]; n = smax nn;

f[t_, x_, y_] := a1*x - b1*x*y;
g[t_, x_, y_] := c1*x*y - d1*y;

Do[x[i] = x0; y[i] = y0, {i, -nn, 0}];
f0 = f[0, x[0], y[0]]; g0 = g[0, x[0], y[0]];

For[k = 1, k <= n, k++, b[k] = k^\[Alpha] - (k - 1)^\[Alpha];
  a[k] = -(2*k^(\[Alpha] + 1)) + (k - 1)^(\[Alpha] + 1) + (k + 
       1)^(\[Alpha] + 1); 
  c[k] = ((j - 1)^(\[Alpha] + 1) - (-\[Alpha] + j - 1)*j^\[Alpha])];

Do[Do[x1[i] = x[i - nn]; y1[i] = y[i - nn];, {i, 0, s*nn}];
  For[j = 1, j <= s*nn, j++, bj = Table[b[j - A], {A, 0, j - 1}]; 
   f1j = Table[f[A*h, x[A], y1[A]], {A, 0, j - 1}]; 
   p[j] = par1 bj . f1j + x[0]; 
   g1j = Table[g[B*h, x1[B], y[B]], {B, 0, j - 1}];
   l[j] = par1 bj . g1j + y[0]; aj = Table[a[j - i], {i, 1, j - 1}]; 
   f2j = Table[f[h*Kk, x[Kk], y1[Kk]], {Kk, 1, j - 1}];
   x[j] = par2 (aj . f2j + f[h*j, p[j], l[j]] + c[j] f0) + x[0]; 
   g2j = Table[g[F*h, x1[F], y[F]], {F, 1, j - 1}];
   y[j] = 
    par2 (aj . g2j + g[h*j, p[j], l[j]] + c[j] g0) + y[0];];, {s, 1, 
   smax}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Part with $\alpha=4/5$ takes 739s. Why this code so slow compare to `NDSolve`? Actually we solve the system of delay integrodifferential equations, while with `NDSolve` we solve DDEs. Visualization

```
Clear[x, y];

a1 = 2/3; b1 = 4/3; c1 = 1; d1 = 1; x0 = 0.9; y0 = 1.8; 
f[t_, x_, y_] := a1*x - b1*x*y;
g[t_, x_, y_] := c1*x*y - d1*y; tau = 0.15;
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == f[t, x[t], y[t - tau]], 
    y'[t] == g[t, x[t - tau], y[t]], x[t /; t <= 0] == 0.9, 
    y[t /; t <= 0] == 1.8}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 15}];


pl1 = ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol[[1]], {t, .0, n h}, 
   PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {x, y}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1/2, PlotStyle -> Green];

Show[pl1, 
 ListLinePlot[lst1, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}, PlotRange -> Full], 
 ListLinePlot[lst2, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Dashed}, PlotRange -> Full]]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Update 1. This problem also can be solved with wavelets collocation method. In the code below we use Haar wavelets. The main limitation of this algorithm is `FindRoot` usage. In this example we use 32 collocation points to compute system of fractional DDE with $\alpha=q=4/5$ up to `t=tmax=10`. It takes about 15s on my laptop.

```
tmax = 10; n = 4; q = 8/10; a1 = 2/3; b1 = 4/3; c1 = 1;
  d1 = 1; x0 = 0.9; y0 = 1.8; tau = 0.15;
 M = Sum[1, {j, 0, n, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 1; dx = 1/M; 
 xl = Table[l dx, {l, 0, M}]; 
 xcol = Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, M + 1}]; 
 xcolN = xcol - 1.*10^-10;
 psi1[x_] := WaveletPsi[HaarWavelet[], x];
 psi2[x_] := WaveletPhi[HaarWavelet[], x];
 psi1jk[x_, j_, k_] := psi1[j x - k];
 psi2jk[x_, j_, k_] := psi2[j x - k];
 psijk[x_, j_, k_] := Sqrt[j] (psi1jk[x, j, k] + psi2jk[x, j, k]); 
 p1i = Table[
   Flatten[Table[
     NIntegrate[psijk[t, 2^j, k], {t, 0, xcol[[i]]}], {j, 0, n, 
      1}, {k, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}]], {i, Length[xcol]}]; 
 pci = Table[
   Flatten[Table[
     NIntegrate[
      psijk[t, 2^j, k]/(xcol[[i]] - t)^q, {t, 0, xcolN[[i]]}], {j, 0, 
      n, 1}, {k, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}]], {i, Length[xcol]}];
 var = Table[
   Flatten[Table[b[i, j, k], {j, 0, n, 1}, {k, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}]], {i, 
    2}]; ic = {.9, 1.8};
 fp = Table[
   Table[var[[j]] . p1i[[i]] + b0[j] xcol[[i]] + ic[[j]], {i, 
     Length[xcol]}], {j, 2}]; 
 fpc = Table[
   Table[var[[j]] . pci[[i]] + b0[j] xcol[[i]]^(1 - q)/(1 - q), {i, 
     Length[xcol]}], {j, 2}]; tn = (1/tmax)^q/Gamma[1 - q];
 p1tau = 
  Table[Flatten[
    Table[NIntegrate[
      psijk[t - tau/tmax, 2^j, k], {t, 0, xcol[[i]]}], {j, 0, n, 
      1}, {k, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}]], {i, Length[xcol]}]; 
 fptau = Table[
   Table[var[[j]] . p1tau[[i]] + b0[j] xcol[[i]] + ic[[j]], {i, 
     Length[xcol]}], {j, 2}];
 eq1 = Table[-fpc[[1, i]] tn + a1*fp[[1, i]] - 
     b1*fp[[1, i]]*fptau[[2, i]] == 0, {i, Length[xcol]}]; 
 eq2 = Table[-fpc[[2, i]] tn - d1*fp[[2, i]] + 
     c1*fp[[2, i]]*fptau[[1, i]] == 0, {i, Length[xcol]}];
 varM = Join[var[[1]], var[[2]], {b0[1], b0[2]}]; 
 sol1 = FindRoot[{eq1, eq2}, 
   Table[{varM[[i]], 1/10}, {i, Length[varM]}]];
```

Visualization along and together with Figure 2

```
lst = Join[{ic}, 
   Table[{fp[[1, i]], fp[[2, i]]} /. sol1, {i, Length[xcol]}]]; 
ListPlot[lst, PlotRange -> Full, PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[.015]}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
```

[image: Figure3]

Update 2. We can improve code above using exact solution for Caputo derivative from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/221609/solver-for-covid-19-epidemic-model-with-the-caputo-fractional-derivatives) as follows

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 h[x_, k_, m_] := 
  WaveletPsi[HaarWavelet[], m x - k, WorkingPrecision -> Infinity];
 p[x_, k_, m_] := 
  Piecewise[{{(1 + k - m*x)/m, 
     k >= 0 && 1/m + (2*k)/m - 2*x < 0 && 1/m + k/m - x >= 0 && 
      m > 0}, {(-k + m*x)/m, 
     k >= 0 && 1/m + (2*k)/m - 2*x >= 0 && k/m - x < 0 && 
      1/m + k/m - x >= 0 && m > 0}}, 0];
 h1[x_] := 
  WaveletPhi[HaarWavelet[], x, WorkingPrecision -> Infinity];
 p1[x_] := Piecewise[{{1, x > 1}}, x];
 pc[t_, k_, m_, q_] := 
  Piecewise[{{-(t^(1 - q)/(-1 + q)), 
     k == 0 && 1/m - 2*t >= 0 && m > 0 && t > 0 && 
      1/m - t >= 
       0}, {-((m^(-1 + q)*(1/(-k + m*t))^(-1 + q))/(-1 + q)), 
     k > 0 && 1/m + (2*k)/m - 2*t > 0 && k/m - t < 0 && m > 0 && 
      1/m + k/m - t > 
       0}, {(-t^q + 2*m*t^(1 + q) - 
        m*t*(-(1/(2*m)) + t)^q)/(t^q*(-(1/(2*m)) + t)^q*(m*(-1 + q))),
      k == 0 && m > 0 && 1/m - 2*t < 0 && 
      1/m - t >= 
       0}, {(1/(-1 + q))*((2^(-1 + q)*
          m^(-1 + 2*q)*(-(-(k/m) + t)^q - 2*k*(-(k/m) + t)^q + 
            2*m*t*(-(k/m) + t)^q + 2*k*(-((1/2 + k)/m) + t)^q - 
            2*m*t*(-((1/2 + k)/m) + t)^q))/((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - 
             m*t))^q), 
     k > 0 && 1/m + (2*k)/m - 2*t == 0 && m > 0 && 
      1/m + k/m - t > 
       0}, {-((1/(-1 + q))*((2^(-1 + q)*
            m^(-1 + 2*q)*(-2*(-((1/2 + k)/m) + t)^
                q*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^q - 
              2*k*(-((1/2 + k)/m) + t)^
                q*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^q + 
              2*m*t*(-((1/2 + k)/m) + t)^
                q*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^
                q + (-((1 + k)/m) + t)^
                q*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^q + 
              2*k*(-((1 + k)/m) + t)^q*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^
                q - 2*m*t*(-((1 + k)/m) + t)^
                q*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^q + (-(k/m) + t)^
                q*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(1 + k - m*t))^q + 
              2*k*(-(k/m) + t)^q*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(1 + k - m*t))^
                q - 2*m*t*(-(k/m) + t)^
                q*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(1 + k - m*t))^q - 
              2*k*(-((1/2 + k)/m) + t)^
                q*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(1 + k - m*t))^q + 
              2*m*t*(-((1/2 + k)/m) + t)^
                q*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(1 + k - m*t))^
                q))/(((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^
             q*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(1 + k - m*t))^q))), 
     k > 0 && m > 0 && 1/m + (2*k)/m - 2*t <= 0 && 
      1/m + k/m - t <= 
       0}, {-((1/(2*
            m*(-1 + q)))*((2^q*m^(2*q)*
             t^q*(-(1/m) + t)^q*(-(1/(2*m)) + t)^q - 
            2^(1 + q)*m^(1 + 2*q)*
             t^(1 + q)*(-(1/m) + t)^q*(-(1/(2*m)) + t)^q - 
            2^(1 + q)*m^(2*q)*t^q*(-(1/(2*m)) + t)^(2*q) + 
            2^(1 + q)*m^(1 + 2*q)*t^(1 + q)*(-(1/(2*m)) + t)^(2*q) + 
            t^q*((-1 + m*t)*(-1 + 2*m*t))^q - 
            2*m*t^(1 + q)*((-1 + m*t)*(-1 + 2*m*t))^q + 
            2*m*t*(-(1/(2*m)) + t)^q*((-1 + m*t)*(-1 + 2*m*t))^q)/(t^
             q*(-(1/(2*m)) + t)^q*((-1 + m*t)*(-1 + 2*m*t))^q))), 
     k == 0 && 1/m - 2*t < 0 && 1/m - t < 0 && 
      m > 0}, {(1/(-1 + q))*((2^(-1 + q)*
          m^(-1 + q)*((-m^q)*(-(k/m) + t)^q - 
            2*k*m^q*(-(k/m) + t)^q + 2*m^(1 + q)*t*(-(k/m) + t)^q + 
            2*k*m^q*(-((1/2 + k)/m) + t)^q - 
            2*m^(1 + q)*
             t*(-((1/2 + k)/m) + t)^q - ((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^
              q*(1/(-1 - 2*k + 2*m*t))^q - 
            2*k*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^
              q*(1/(-1 - 2*k + 2*m*t))^q + 
            2*m*t*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^
              q*(1/(-1 - 2*k + 2*m*t))^q))/((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - 
             m*t))^q), 
     1/m + (2*k)/m - 2*t < 0 && k > 0 && m > 0 && 1/m + k/m - t > 0}},
    0];
 
 pc1[t_, q_] := 
  Piecewise[{{-(t^(1 - q)/(-1 + q)), 
     t <= 1}}, -(((-1 + t)^q*t + t^q - t^(1 + q))/((-1 + t)^q*
        t^q*(-1 + q)))];
 tmax = 10; q = 8/10; tn = 1/tmax^q/Gamma[1 - q]; a1 = 2/3; b1 = 4/3; 
 c1 = 1; d1 = 1; x0 = 0.9; y0 = 1.8; tau = 0.15; J = 5; M = 2^J; 
 dx = 1/(2*M); xl = Table[l dx, {l, 0, 2 M}]; 
 xcol = Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, 2 M + 1}];
 x1[t_, q_] := 
  Sum[v[i, j] pc[t, i, 2^j, q], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
   v1 pc1[t, q];
 x[t_] := 
  Sum[v[i, j] p[t, i, 2^j], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
   v1 p1[t] + v0;
 y1[t_, q_] := 
  Sum[u[i, j] pc[t, i, 2^j, q], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
   u1 pc1[t, q];
 y[t_] := 
  Sum[u[i, j] p[t, i, 2^j], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
   u1 p1[t] + u0;
 varM = Join[{v0, v1, u0, u1}, 
   Flatten[Table[v[i, j], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}]], 
   Flatten[Table[u[i, j], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}]]];
 eq[q_] := 
  Flatten[
   Table[{-x1[t, q] tn + a1 x[t] - b1 x[t] y[t - tau/tmax] == 
      0, -y1[t, q] tn - d1 y[t] + c1 y[t] x[t - tau/tmax] == 0}, {t, 
     xcol}]]; ic = {x[0] == .9, y[0] == 1.8};
 sol = FindRoot[Join[eq[q], ic], 
   Table[{varM[[i]], 1/10}, {i, Length[varM]}]];]
```

It takes 4s only for 64 collocation points. As a bonus we have interpolation function for `x[t], y[t]`. Visualization

```
ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/2, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
```

[image: Figure 4]

Comment: Thansk for your response. Can you please try to check the result for `{t,0,15}` for both `alpha=1` and `alpha=4/5`?

Comment: @zhk Please, see update to my answer.

Comment: Would it be faster with wavelets method?

Comment: @zhk Actually we don't know, but we can try to solve this problem using the Euler wavelets collocation method and compare time with predictor-corrector algorithm.

Comment: If possible for you then please?

Comment: @zhk Please, see Update 1 to my answer. In this example code with wavelets 30 times faster than predictor-corrector algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. Can you please use Wavelets to solve the diffusion equation in cylindrical coordinates given in this post https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/276896/

Comment: It would be more convenient if the final solution are represented by interpolating functions.

Comment: @zhk Do you mean `x[t], y[t]`?

Comment: Yes! that’s right.

Comment: @zhk See Update 2 to my answer.